# MySQL FULLTEXT search quirk?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a FULLTEXT index on a column which contains a few hundred thousand UK street names.

When looking up the following strings, I am getting bizarre behaviour:

1. Searching for "ash row" - returns result
2. Searching for "ash way" - no result

I have run further tests and it seems something doesn't like the word "way" for some reason. All lookups for the word "way" (and which I know to have valid entries on the DB) return no results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

.........................